# How to only connect to one SSID (access point) Win 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, security, ssid

I have searched for this solution but have not found an answer. How do I only connect to one SSID / Access Point (ie. my router). I do not want to keep pinging/roaming other routers in my neighborhood. I am running Win 8.1 and have a Dell Wireless card. Another way to look at it - I would like to whitelist my router and blacklist everything else.

Thanks!

Comment: Switch to a wired network... The very function of wireless networking has your card always searching for available networks, but it will not connect to them unless you implicitly tell it to. It is not "pinging" other routers or roaming to them (unless you tell it to) as long as your SSID and passphrase is unique, it simply listens to other signals that are being broadcast but it doesn't send anything to them unless you tell it to. I am not sure I understand the problem...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. A wired solution isn't possible at my office. I know there must be a way to limit the available SSID / Access points that a logged in user can see.

Comment: I didn't say it can't be done, because it can via GPO, and a quick Google search got me the answer quickly, several actually. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=group+policy+block+wireless+ssid

Comment: That's it. Thanks! It helps knowing the proper search terms!

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked for you. I will submit an answer so it can be accepted and the question closed

Answer (score 0):

This is done via Windows Group Policy, and a quick Google search got me the answer quickly, several actually. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=group+policy+block+wireless+ssid